# Why does the photo for my Apple ID and my wife's Apple ID periodically swap?

Tags: apple-id, family-sharing

For years, every week or so on our Macs, my AppleID photo and my wife's AppleID photo swap.   I go to System Preferences/Apple ID and edit the photo to select a photo of myself.   I made a photo of myself a "favorite" so I could find one quickly because this happens so often.

I just did this, and my AppleID photo got changed.   But so did my wife's (She's the organizer)